# predicting N probabilities for each pixel in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

I Am developing a **classification based-model** to predict 12 probability for each **pixel** in the image , I have built the architecture , but I am not sure whether I am right or not , I am a newbie in **deep learning**.

**EDIT 1 :** I was adviced to use the fully convolutional approach , which means never using the Fully connected layers , I did try that , that gave me a better saturated predicted channels , but they were never the best , here is my architecture , Any Help ??

**Edit 1 Architecture :**

```
def Build_Classification_Model():
    Kernel_Size_Val=4
    import keras
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Reshape,concatenate,BatchNormalization,Dropout,Activation,Conv2D,MaxPool2D

    Input_Img=Input(shape=(Img_Size,Img_Size,1),name='Main_Input')
    #The First Conv Layer + BatchNormalization
    X=Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='First_Conv_0',padding='same')(Input_Img)
    X=Conv2D(filters=4,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='First_Conv_1',padding='same')(X)

    X=Conv2D(filters=8,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Second_Con_0',padding='same')(X)
    X=Conv2D(filters=8,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Second_Conv_1',padding='same')(X)

    X=Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Third_Conv_0',padding='same')(X)
    X=Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Third_Conv_1',padding='same')(X)

    X=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Fourth_Conv_0',padding='same')(X)
    X=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Fourth_Conv_1',padding='same')(X)

    X=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Fifth_Conv_0',padding='same')(X)
    X=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='relu',name='Fifth_Conv_1',padding='same')(X)


    U=Conv2D(filters=Num_Bins+1,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='softmax',padding='same')(X)
    V=Conv2D(filters=Num_Bins+1,kernel_size=Kernel_Size_Val,activation='softmax',padding='same')(X)

    X=concatenate([Input_Img,U,V])

    MyModel=Model(Input_Img,X)
    MyModel.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(MyModel.summary())
    return MyModel
```

**The following is the function for my baseline architecture** :

```
def Build_Classificion_U_Model():
        import keras
        from keras.models import Model
        from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Reshape,concatenate,BatchNormalization,Permute,Dropout
        from keras.layers import Conv2D
        from keras import regularizers 

        Input_Img=Input(shape=(Img_Size,Img_Size,1),name='Main_Input')     

        #The First Conv Layer + BatchNormalization
        X=Conv2D(filters=8,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',name='Conv1')(Input_Img)
        #The Second Conv Layer + BatchNormalization
        X=Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',name='Conv2')(X)
         #The Third Conv Layer + BatchNormalization
        X=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=5,activation='relu',name='Convfsf3d')(X)

        X=Flatten()(X)

        X=Dense(units=256,activation='relu')(X)
        X=Dense(units=49152,activation='relu')(X)
        X=Reshape(target_shape=(Img_Size,Img_Size,12))(X)
        X=Conv2D(filters=12,kernel_size=1,activation='softmax')(X)
        X=concatenate(inputs=[Input_Img,X])

        MyModel=Model(Input_Img,X)
        MyModel.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(MyModel.summary())
        return MyModel
```

I will explain my architecture , the input is about a 64 * 64 * 1 graysale image , followed by many convolution layers and then it is flattened then there it is followed by many FC Layers but the final one is 49152 to be reshaped back to ( 64 * 64* 12 ) 12 here represents the probabilities and then concatenated with the input layer , to be compared with the output but it give me so bad results , why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably this layer:
`X=Dense(units=256,activation='relu')(X)` which has only 256 units.

It is not reasonable to expect that the information of all 49152 probability values can be compressed into just 256 values. In the process, a lot of information is necessarily lost. Therefore, you should make this layer much bigger, at least a few thousand units.

Another thing is that using fully connected layers is probably a poor way of doing this. Instead, try a fully convolutional approach where you keep using convolutional layers all the way through.

Comment: I did try the fully convolutional approach , but gives me relatively bad results :S